# How can I rename a table in MonetDB?

Tags: monetdb, table-rename

How can I rename a table in monetdb?
The typical SQL statement `ALTER TABLE name RENAME TO new_name` is not supported.

Comment: maybe `CREATE TABLE newname AS SELECT * FROM oldname WITH DATA;  DROP TABLE oldname;` ?

Comment: ^is correct solution. [I have tried renaming system db entries failed and you don't want to do that]

Comment: I have tried `CREATE TABLE newname AS SELECT * FROM oldname WITH DATA; DROP TABLE oldname;` and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @pic, please accept Lin_n's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider creating a SQL view with the new name, e.g.
    CREATE VIEW newname AS SELECT * FROM oldname;

This has the advantage of no data being copied around at all.

Comment: hi hannes - is there a similar approach for renaming columns? from what I found on the monetdb mailing lists it seems like the `rename column` syntax is not supported [1](https://www.monetdb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2478)/[2](https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2009-February/002551.html). namely - got a column named `Key` which somehow got mangled throuh `monet.read.csv()` into `ï..Key`. (p.s. `monetdblite`)

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] [ schema_name . ] table_name RENAME TO  new_table_name
```

It's supported since 2019 [MonetDB website](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/SQLSyntaxOverview#ALTER_TABLE_RENAME)

Comment: Verified this works using version 11.33.3 (April 2019).